# How can you store sensitive information (AWS log on) in an Angular app?

Tags: angular, security, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, angular-cli

We're making an app using the Angular CLI, using Angular 4. A part of this app is to upload images to our CDN hosted on Amazon S3. At the minute, i'm storing the AWS credentials just into variables, which is obviously not suitable for a production environment.

In .NET I would use a config file, would there be anything similar for an Angular app? Thanks

Comment: have a JSON file on your local machine. add that to .gitignore. read the file and assign to the variables wherever necessary.

Comment: Store in the DB?